# How to set the Am and Pm value to the Time Picker In windows phone 7 C#

Tags: silverlight, datepicker, windows-phone, timepicker

> i am using time picker in windows phone to add the event 
>   i am setting time ex 2.30 pm and i am stored the value in db
>
> next in update page i am setting the value to timepicker the value getting form database
>
> Code to set the value for time picker

```
`updateEventTimePicker.Value = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(eventdatee[2]), Convert.ToInt32(eventdatee[1]), Convert.ToInt32(eventdatee[0]), Convert.ToInt32(eventTimee[0]), Convert.ToInt32(eventTimee[1]),1);`
```

the problem is when i add in db the time was 2.30 pm but when i retrieve the value it sets 2.30 am how to set the AM and PM value

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the am or pm in the DateTime class. It is in a 24 hr format.
 you can use this function i wrote to get your hour or minute in a 24 hr format.

```
   public string [] get24hrFormat(string [] eventTime, string amOrpm)
    {
        amOrpm=amOrpm.ToLower();
        string [] newTime= new string[2];
        if(amOrpm=="am")
        {
            newTime[0]=eventTime[0];
            newTime[1]=eventTime[1];
            return newTime;
        }

        else 
        {
            if (amOrpm == "pm")
            {
                if (eventTime[0] != "12")
                {
                    newTime[0] = eventTime[0] + 12;
                    newTime[1] = eventTime[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    newTime[0] = eventTime[0];
                    newTime[1] = eventTime[1];

                }
            }
                return newTime;

        }
    }
```